# What type of rheostat can I use to control an LED bulb?

Tags: electrical

I am making an Edison wooden lamp and instead of a toggle on/off switch, I want to be able to dim the lamp.  The bulb I am using is rated at 6 Watts.  What type of rotary rheostat should I use for the dimming function?  It needs to work at 120V.

Many rheostats I am seeing are rated for 100W which may not properly dim an LED given their low wattage.

Comment: What do you mean by "rheostat", are you referring to a dimmer?

Comment: Yes essentially a dimmer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.   Get a dimmable LED and use a standard inline light dimmer.

Comment: The bulb I have is a dimmable LED made by Fait. Standard light dimmers are rather bulky. I was hoping to use a low profile rotary rheostat.

Comment: Rheostats lower the voltage.  Dimmers "cut" chunks out of the AC wave form to reduce power.  That's why the cheap ones buzz.   They aren't interchangeable.

Comment: What about a dimmer [like this 300W 120V rotary unit](https://www.grandbrass.com/item/dib03/)?

Comment: That looks like it will work fine.   I'm pretty sure you don't have a 300W LED!

Comment: Yes the LED is only 6 Watts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Above is right.  Use a standard light dimmer and make sure your bulb says "dimmable" on the package
2. The 100W rating for a rheostat is the power it can sink, has nothing to do with the LED's rated power.   You would, if you did try a rheostat, need to pick a proper resistance.  That requires some circuit analysis and math.   It'd be trivial for me, but then again I'm an electronics engineer.   And being an EE, I would use a standard light dimmer   ;)